# How to force TestNG to run all methods in class without switching to another thread in parallel mode

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I have the following suite XML for running UI tests using Webdriver:

```
 <suite name="test suite" verbose="3" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">

<test name="extended_smoke_test_suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener
            ...
        </listener>
    </listeners>   
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="somegroup1" />
            <include name="somegroup2" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <packages>
           <package name="tests.*" ></package>
    </packages>
</test>
```

When I run this suite, it launches a few browsers(more than 2) and I can observe that it works only in two of them.
Looks like it starts some test class(TestClass1), executes one of the test methods, and then switches to another class(TestClass2). After completing the test method in TestClass2 it returns back to TestClass1 and continues with it

As I have lots of test classes this results in multiple open browsers.

Is there any way to "say" TestNG to execute all tests from TestClass1 and only after that switch to next, so we will have only two opened and active browsers at the current moment

Comment: I had a same issue, resolved using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458034/testng-parallel-classes-and-dependsonmethods

Comment: ref: https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2018/11/23/thread-affinity-in-testng/#:~:text=To%20enable%20this%20feature%20(This,affinity%3Dtrue%E2%80%9D.&text=As%20you%20can%20see%20from,()%E2%80%9D%20on%20the%20same%20thread.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me to resolve this issue you should investigate in maven surefire plugin direction.
Currently i use it for excluding my test suite on build.

pom.xml in my local  module

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<includes>-->
                        <!--<include>**/*.class</include>-->
                    <!--</includes>-->
                    <excludedGroups>com.exadel.rms.selenium.SeleniumTests</excludedGroups>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I annotate my test class to exlude with

```
 @Category(SeleniumTests.class)
    public class HomePageTestSuite extends BaseSeleniumTest {
............
```

And the whole structure you can see on the picture:
[image]

Actually you can get some useful info for [here](http://johndobie.blogspot.com/2012/04/unit-and-integration-tests-with-maven.html)

Look also this topic. Prolly it can be also useful: [JUnit: Can (should) this be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335034/junit-can-should-this-be-done)

Hope this helps you)

Comment: Thanks a lot for so detailed answer:) But if I am not mistaken you are describing how this could be done with JUnit not with TestNG.

Answer (score -1):

You have setup your TestNG configuration to run tests parallel:

```
<suite name="test suite" verbose="3" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
```

If you have only two classes: TestClass1 and TestClass2, then TestNG will create 2 threads and will invoke tests from TestClass1 in one thread, and TestClass2 in the other.

If you want TestClass2 run after TestClass1 you have several options:

1.Make class TestClass2 dependant on TestClass1. There multiple options here, so just refer to [Dependcies](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) section of TestNG documentation.

2.Set `thread-count="1"` and `parallel="false"` (or remove parallel attribute). Also make sure you don't have `preserve-order="false"` and put your  TestClass2 after TestClass1 in xml.

```
<test name="extended_smoke_test_suite">
    <classes>
        <class name="test.TestClass1"/>
        <class name="test.TestClass2"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: I have much more then two tests - this was just an example. The goal is not just make some dependencies between test classes. The problem is that when I launch this suit on webdriver grid with two nodes and test class has few test method inside  - part of method is succesfully passed and testng switches to another test class. But as first was not fully finished it still occupies webdriver grid node and just waits till testng returns to finish thi first test