# TestNG parallel="classes" and dependsOnMethods

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

Running the following TestNG xml suite:

```
<suite name="MySuite" verbose="1" configfailurepolicy="continue" >
 <test name="some-tests" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="tmp" />
...
```

with test class

```
@Slf4j
public class TmpTest {

    @Test(groups = "tmp")
    void test1()
    {
      log.debug("test1");
    }

    @Test(groups = "tmp", dependsOnMethods = "test1")
    void test2()
    {
        log.debug("test2");
    }

}
```

Should results with single thread as both tests are in the same class

Apparently there are 2 threads:

```
15:35:59.353 [TestNG-test=some-tests-1] DEBUG TmpTest - test1
15:35:59.362 [TestNG-test=some-tests-2] DEBUG TmpTest - test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is open TestNG issue https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1185
parallel="**classes**" and **dependsOnMethods** does not work together as expected

Comment: You can perhaps accept your answer. This is still an open issue in TestNG

Comment: Please check this answer: [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185500/when-parallelizings-tests-using-testng-tests-in-a-class-do-not-get-executed-in). Hope it helps.